# Returning the Best Decision Tree From Cross Validation In Matlab

Tags: matlab, validation, tree, classification

When using Matlab, what is the correct means of finding the model with the least error from a cross validated fitting? My goal is to show the error rates of the best, cross validated decision tree as a function of the size of test data and have the following code:

```
chess = csvread(filename);
predictors = chess(:,1:6);
class = chess(:,7);

cvpart = cvpartition(class,'holdout', 0.3);
Xtrain = predictors(training(cvpart),:);
Ytrain = class(training(cvpart),:);
Xtest = predictors(test(cvpart),:);
Ytest = class(test(cvpart),:);

numElements = numel(training(cvpart));
trainErrorGrowing = zeros(numElements,1);
testErrorGrowing = zeros(numElements,1);

for n = 100:numElements
    data = datasample(training(cvpart), n);
    dataX = predictors(data,:);
    dataY = class(data,:);

    % Fit the decision tree
    tree = fitctree(dataX, dataY, 'AlgorithmForCategorical', 'PullLeft', 'CrossVal', 'on');

    % Loop to find the model with the least error
    kfoldError = 100;
    bestTree = tree.Trained{1};
    for i = 1:10
        err = loss(tree.Trained{i}, Xtrain, Ytrain);
        if err < kfoldError
            kfoldError = err;
            bestTree = tree.Trained{i};
        end
    end
    trainErrorGrowing(n) = loss(bestTree,Xtest,Ytest,'Subtrees','all'); % Training Error
    testErrorGrowing(n) = loss(bestTree,Xtest,Ytest,'Subtrees','all'); % Testing Error
end

plot(numElements,testErrorGrowing);
```

It is important to the metrics that the data used for the final testing not be used in any way to train the tree. However, when I try to execute this code, I get the error

```
Error using classreg.learning.internal.classCount
You passed an unknown class '1' of type double.
```

on the line

```
err = loss(tree.Trained{i}, Xtrain, Ytrain);
```

I have tried casting the iterator in an int8 and a char, but receive the same error both times. Is there a simpler way to find the resulting decision tree with the least error, or at least a way to reference the individual trained trees?

Comment: If I get your question, cross validation is not meant to change the classifier, rather the dataset on which it is trained. I think you want a hyper-parameter optimisation technique, like grid search, to detect the best parametrisation of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are doing 10-fold cross validation while learning the model. You can then use the kfoldLoss function to also get the CV loss for each fold and then choose the trained model that gives you the least CV loss in the following way:

```
modelLosses = kfoldLoss(tree,'mode','individual');
```

The above code will give you a vector of length 10 (10 CV error values) if you have done 10-fold cross-validation while learning. Assuming the trained model with least CV error is the 'k'th one, you would then use:

```
testSetPredictions = predict(tree.Trained{k}, testSetFeatures);
```